# Добавить ImageView на экран в определенном месте

Tags: android

Пытаюсь добавить ImageView в определенных координатах на экране, но почему-то ImageView размещается ниже и в бок на 20-40 пикселей...

Вот код добавления:

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();

    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.black_background);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.leftMargin = x;
    params.topMargin = y;
    rootView.addView(iv, params);

    return false;
}
```

Вот xml разметки:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/rootView"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/ll"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  </LinearLayout>

<TableLayout

android:id="@+id/tl1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/ll"
android:gravity="center"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Как разместить ImageView в нужных мне координатах ?

**UPD:**
Эксперементальным путем было установленно, что примерно на 155пикселей вниз уходит ImageView.

Отнял размер экшн бара, LinearLayout - расстояние стало меньше, но все равно пикселей 60 еще по высоте не то.

```
params.topMargin = y-actionBarHeight-(int)linearLayout.getX();
```

Comment: padding контейнера учитываете?

Comment: Может надо учитывать высоту ActionBar?

Comment: Паддинг не учитываю. Но не в нем дело.

Comment: @RuslanA вряд ли.

Comment: попробуйте все-таки убрать падинги, и проверить без них

Comment: Что происходит и что ожидается? Вы хотите по тачу пальцем разместить ImageView, так чтобы его верхний левый угол был в месте тача?

Comment: @metalurgus ок, сейчас попробую.

Comment: @anber ага, именно так)

Comment: @metalurgus убрал паддинги у рут элемента - теперь нет смещения вправо, но ImageView все равно смещен на 40, а то и 50 пикселей вниз от точки клика на экран.

Comment: весь падинг убрали? и `android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"` тоже? Кроме того, как сказал – Ruslan A, вы не учитываете так же и ActionBar. Проще всего будет ввести поправку на отступ у `rootView`, получив его динамически в момент добавления `ImageView`

Comment: @metalurgus да, паддинг весь убрал, даже справа) А как расчитать того с учетом экшн бара ?

Comment: получаете позицию `rootView` на экране https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20get%20view%20position%20on%20screen&es_th=1 Дальше отнимаете у `x` и `y` отсюда `params.leftMargin = x;
    params.topMargin = y`  значения позиции `rootView` слева и сверху соответственно

Comment: @metalurgus обновил, посмотрите, пожалуйста

Comment: никто кроме вас не занет, что такое `actionBarHeight` и `linearLayout.getX()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();

    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.black_background);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
//Так можно расчитать отступы
    int[] rootLocation = new int[2];
    rootView.getLocationOnScreen(rootLocation);

    int relativeLeft = rootLocation[0];
    int relativeTop  = rootLocation[1];
//end
    params.leftMargin = x - relativeLeft;//поправка на отступы
    params.topMargin = y - relativeTop;//поправка на отступы
    rootView.addView(iv, params);

    return false;
}
```

Comment: @Andrew, да, точно. Поправил.

Comment: @Andrew, так бывает, когда делаешь что-то *на коленке* :-)

Comment: все ок) спасибо! Вы решили проблему!

Comment: Ураа) Вы решили проблему глобальную(для меня)!)